# Migrating Node and MEAN versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, meanjs

I recently moved from Node version 4.x to 6.x and from [meanjs.org](http://meanjs.org) 0.3.x to 0.4.2.

Everything was going ok until I started working with Users.

Basically none of my Users are able to sign in, after having investigated it a bit I found an error:

```
DeprecationWarning: crypto.pbkdf2 without specifying a digest is deprecated. Please specify a digest
```

I updated the `crypto.pbkdf2Sync` adding `'sha1'` as last parameter in the `hashPassword` method:

```
crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, new Buffer(this.salt, 'base64'), 10000, 64, 'sha1').toString('base64');
```

It removed the nodejs error but unfortunately not solved the User sign in issue, they are still unable to log in.

How can I solve this? Thanks